# Cant get result on from PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I trying to create quiz. For now, i create changing questions, and result, but... the thing is i get result only when i use submit form and only for 1st question (reloading page)... My main thing is that i cant reload page.I try to do it with ajax but i get error like(maybe becouse i have no idea how ajax works):

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $choice is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):20)
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
> at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2) (anonymous) @ (index):20 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2 y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
> ```

My code:
Part from Main Code:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <script >
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#result").click(function(){
                    post_data = {$choice}
     $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                data: post_data,
                url: 'grade.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    result = data;
                    alert(result)
                }
    })
                    $("#points").load("grade.php");
                    });

            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="quiz">
     <?php 
        $sql= "SELECT* FROM quiz ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $ans_array = array($row['choice1'] ,$row['choice2'] , $row['choice3'] , $row['choice4'] ,  $row['correct'] );
        shuffle($ans_array);
        $choice = "quizid".$row['quizId'];
        ?> 


    <h3><?=$row['topic'];?></h3>
    <h4><?=$row['question'];?></h4>
    <div>
       <input type="radio" name="$choice" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>"><label id="<?= $ans_array[0];?>">A) <?= $ans_array[0];?></label></br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="$choice" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"><label id="<?= $ans_array[1];?>">B) <?= $ans_array[1];?></label></br>
    </div>

    <div>
       <input type="radio" name="$choice" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"><label id="<?= $ans_array[2];?>">C) <?= $ans_array[2];?></label></br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="$choice" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"><label id="<?= $ans_array[3];?>">D) <?= $ans_array[3];?></label></br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="$choice" value="<?=$ans_array[4]?>"><label id="<?= $ans_array[4];?>">E) <?= $ans_array[4];?></label></br>
    </div>

</div>

        <p id="points"></p> 
        <button id="result">check</button>

        <button id="next">next question</button>
```

PHP: grade.php

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
$sql= "SELECT* FROM quiz";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$answer = $_GET['$choice']; 


    $totalCorrect = 0;

    if ($answer ==  $row['correct']) { $totalCorrect++; }


    echo "$totalCorrect / 15 correct";

?>
```

What i need to do:
1. Display question
2. Check if answer is correct
3. Count correct answears
4. Move to next question
And over and over...

Any help will be high recommended. I stack since 3 days, can't go farther.

Comment: here's the error `post_data = {$choice}` - what did you want to do there??

Comment: if it should be this: `$choice = "quizid".$row['quizId'];`, then there's some missunderstanding of what code runs where (client/server) happening.

Comment: It workig without ajax. Becouse I have row in database quizId. So each question have diffrent $choice. When I create Form with submit button I can check correct answer on serwer. But that form reload my page.

Comment: I think I get it. Becouse $choice working on serwer side  client side won't see it. But if I create function that will pass the value for choice from php in to javascript it may works. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: jup, that's it. There could be a possibility in re-structuring your code (moving javascript/ajax down, so that you can paste in $choice there). Not nice, but could work.